# Why shouldn't I use IdToken as bearer token in an IDP context?

Tags: authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, auth0

I am using an IDP platform (here AWS Cognito but that could be Auth0, OKTA or Keycloak) and I was wondering why I was discouraged to use the `ID Token` as an authorization token.

To be more specific, I will not make use of a resource server with authorization delegation from a user to a third-party app. My IDP will just let me SSO all my users on my different applications. There is no scope to grant here, only authentication claims that each service will use to grant or refuse access to resources (like an email, user ID, or the roles).

I understand I could provide my application with the `id token` and then create some session for my user. By why shouldn't I use the `id token` itself as a stateless session token, given that its signature can be checked on each application's back-end ?

And if I *should* use an `access token` over the `id token` - can I replace scopes by roles ? Or how should I understand the scopes in a non-delegation context (*"user is usign the app himself, not giving permission" vs "user is giving all scopes to the SPA front-end which is an application in itself"*)

By the way, I am recovering the tokens through code PKCE flow on the front end.

Answer (score 2):

The ID token only contains details about the user and how the user authenicated. so its perfect for creating a longer lasting cookie session with the user. The default lifetime for and ID-token is very short as well, like minutes. You typically throw the id-token away after establishing the sesson. You should never ever pass the ID-token around to other services.

The access token is mean to give you access to the APIs that the token is intended for.

when the user signs in, you ask for acceess to certain scopes and the scopes selected (consented) by the user , then is included in the access token (as scopes and audience claims).

In theory you can pass the ID-token to an API, bits not how its supposed to work.
See [this](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901860/why-shouldnt-i-use-idtoken-as-bearer-token-in-an-idp-context) for more details:

Comment: Okay. But what now if I use the id-token as a stateless sesison token, lasting minutes is fine (the access token doesn't last any more) with refresh token called periodically. In this case remember that I am not sending the id-token to any third party services but use it to autenticate from my front end to my back end. Does it sound too bad ? And, if so, why ?

Comment: Ok, I am aware of the first link even though : `Do not use ID tokens to gain access to an API. ... the audience of the ID ... must be the client ID of the application making the authentication request. If this is not the case, you should not trust the token.` and I am indeed sending the id token to client requesting it with the proper id. So then I don't understand why should it be discouraged. But in case it is, how would you go about letting the app manage authorization through roles defined on the user ?

Comment: The ID-token can contains personal information, like name , address ,email.. (like a driver-license/passport), but you dont want to give that away to third parties and APIs, instead like at the hotel, you get a key , that is aimed for accessing resources.  You don't use your identity to access things....

Comment: Except when the service use identity to grant authorisatio in itself, like when you go to the post office and retrieve a parcel with your id card. Authentication let them authorize you. In my case my API is a first party. My clients are supposed to get complete access, and the API will manage authorisation based on user id and roles. Actually, I think those could get in the access token - but not with AWS Cognito, which is maybe the origin of my confusion - because they do not follow completely standards and encourage Id token as an authorization method.

Comment: Maybe is not the same context, but Kubernetes uses id_tokens as authorization mean: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens